# How to resolve IBM websphere AMQ4574 error

Tags: ibm-mq

How to resolve error-'*IBM WebSphere Explorer is already running(AMQ4574)*'?
I am getting this error while accessing IBM explorer through ssh.

Comment: MQExplorer is a GUI. It's can be accessed via SSH.

Comment: Shashi - You can ssh in and set DISPLAY to another box before launching it

Comment: Thanks Jason. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you cant have more than one explorer running under the same userid anymore...

Read the following for the explanation and potential workaround
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21672390